# ASUS gl553vd bios update with no battery

Tags: bios, uefi, asus-laptop

I want to update my bios because the battery is not charging. my laptop model is Asus Gl553vd. after using flash drive in UEFI bios in ezflash3 i select the bios file, its showing me the error of 20 % battery as i searched there is a risky method for legacy bios but how about here? really appreciate your helps it is so necessary for me.

Comment: Will updating the BIOS fix the battery not taking a charge? Most likely not. Time to get a new battery.

Comment: Is charge feature corrupted from previous Bios mods for overclocking? battery cant be that old. Is it?  Use EZbios method. I think they disable downgrading Bios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Laptops (no exceptions I know of) require a modestly charged battery and an AC connection to be able to update BIOS.

The reason is that a power failure can damage the BIOS and require replacement of the motherboard (to replace the BIOS).

Do not attempt this, but rather wait until you have replaced the Battery and then update BIOS.